# Troubleshooting a .htaccess wildcard subdomain rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have been working on this problem for a 3 solid days and posted on several forums with no leads.

Problem:

**When a user types in SUBDOMAIN.domain.com I want it to stay that way in the URL window.**

The real location of these files is domain.com/apps/SUBDOMAIN

I know that this is possible using a .domain.com DNS A record (which I have done) and a .htaccess rule.

This is my .htaccess rule at the moment

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/) /apps/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

Ok, this almost works.

Typing in subdomain.domain.com is reading from domain.com/apps/subdomain

BUT something is going horribly wrong.

Visiting subdomain.domain.com/image.jpg (AKA domain.com/apps/subdomain) works fine

Visiting subdomain.domain.com/anyfolder/image.jpg (AKA domain.com/apps/subdomain) returns a 404

Looking at the Cpanel Error log shows this

```
[Thu Nov 18 20:48:50 2010] [error] [client ***.**.***.***] File does not exist: /home/domain/public_html/images, referer: http://subdomain.domain.com/apps/subdomain/
```

So it appears to be correctly rewriting on a first directory basis but anything lower then that gets sent back to public_html root

All help and advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Tim

PS. I had to remove the proper hyperlink formatting as I am a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the rewrite rule you have:

```
RewriteRule !^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/) /apps/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

says: rewrite only if `^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/)` does **not** match. When your URL path is `/anyfolder/image.jpg`, the above will match (`^anyfolder/`), thus rewrite rule will **not** be run, so you will basically continue to `subdomain.domain.com/anyfolder/image.jpg`.

The following SO question has a similar requirement:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

In his answer, glavić gives the response that should work, also gives this link:

- http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3163397.htm

Try it out, it should work OK.

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked really well. It's perfect. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Glad to help Tim!

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you. If you have time I have posted another question you may be able to help with as it is sort of an extension to this one. http://serverfault.com/questions/205396/adding-a-rule-to-my-htaccess-subdomain-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the httpd.conf? It seems much more straightforward to use dynamic virtual hosts. Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html