# Adding a rule to my htaccess subdomain rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I recently had some help from icyrock.com with a htaccess rewrite that sends all subdomain requests to domain.com/apps

You can find the thread [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/203780/troubleshooting-a-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-rewrite) and the code is here:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

#### URL Rewrite Handler for Subdomains (by Randall Krause) ####

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) apps/%1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```

As I said this works really well, but I need to add two more rules that I am having trouble integrating without conflicting with the above code.

1. For any requests that are NOT for subdomains I need the main website URL (http://domain.com) to rewrite to http: // www.domain.com
2. For any requests that are NOT for the subdomains I also need to rewrite the URLS to remove an index.php from the URL.

The code for this is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Adding this in its current form BEFORE the subdomain rewrite rule breaks it.

The only solution I have found is to explicitly define which files are not to be covered by the above rule by doing something like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but try something along these lines (you might need to tweak it):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:index.php)?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Put the code after `RewriteEngine On` (i.e. before your first `RewriteCond`). Note that it's going to remove **all** `index.php` endings (i.e. `domain.com/a/b/c/index.php` will become `www.domain.com/a/b/c/`. Taken from here:

- http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/226.htm

I suggest you do some reading on mod_rewrite, such as:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
- http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html

if you are going to need it every second day - pays off... :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying and appologies for bothering you yet again. The www. redirect works without conflicting (Thanks), but it is not removing the index.php. I have been looking through the links you posted but they give me a case of information overload. Thanks for all your help. I will keep searching! Tim

Comment: Also, I took out (?:index.php) and nothing changed. Does anyone have any information on this???

Comment: Try this then: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:/index.php)?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]`.

Comment: No sorry. I don't know why it isnt't working. I don't know if it's because I am using codeigniter but I have set all the config options to the right url.

Comment: Do you have your `RewriteLog` turned on? See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog and this SOq: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215316/how-do-i-troubleshoot-why-my-rewrite-rules-arent-being-applied-by-apache. This will allow you to see what is happening - you may want to post that back to your question.